# Can't delete Cookies in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, cookies, jwt

I've been looking everywhere on how to delete cookies and it all boils down to : setting the cooking at a time that has passed and no matter what I try, when I do exactly that, it simply does not work.

```
public function login(string $username, string $password) {

        $user = \repository\UserRepo::userExists($username);

        // Check if the account exists
        if ($user) {
            // Check if the informations given are correct
            if ($user->password == $password) {
                // Connecting the client
                session_start();
                $jwt = $this->generateJWT($user->name);
                setcookie('jwt', $jwt, httponly: true);
                setcookie('name', $user->name, httponly: true);
                header('Location: /Catalog');
            }
            else {
                // Warn client that the password is wrong
                include __DIR__ . "/../view/login.php";
            }
        }
        else {
            // Warn client that no user under that name exist
            include __DIR__ . "/../view/login.php";
        }
    }

    public function generateJWT(string $username) : string {
        $header = json_encode(['typ' => 'JWT']);
        $payload = json_encode(['username' => $username]);

        $encodedHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));
        $encodedPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_decode($payload));

        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $encodedHeader . "." . $encodedPayload, 'YEET', true);

        $encodedSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));

        //enfin le JWT
        $jwt = $encodedHeader . "." . $encodedPayload . "." . $encodedSignature;
        return $jwt;
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        setcookie("jwt", "", time() - 3600, httponly: true);
        setcookie("name", "", time() - 3600, httponly: true);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION = [];
        header('Location: /Catalog');
    }
```

Here is all the code you should need. When I call the "disconnect" function, it goes all the way through it since I get redirected to /Catalog but it doesn't delete the cookies as I'm asking in the first couple lines of my "disconnect" function.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit : I found out why, I need to give the cookies a path when I create them and specify that same path when I delete them.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the header is being received by the browser as-expected? Because after that it's entirely up to the browser as for what happens to the cookie.